# Drupal 8: How to unpublish node when user clicked on Delete button

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

On my website, The user can add the content and edit the content. On the edit page, there is one delete button to delete the content but I want to use that button to just hide/unpublish the content from the user and the public.

```
I have tried the below code but it is deleting the content.  

function test_entity_predelete(Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface $entity) {
    $nid = $entity->id();
    $node  =Node::load($nid);
    $node->setPublished(FALSE);
    $node->save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly, do not allow users to delete nodes - by the proper
   permissions settings.
2. Secondly add Publish/Unpublish button or just
   show users Publish checkbox on edit form and instruct them how to
   use it and how it works.

Maybe combination of modules can be helpful:

1. https://www.drupal.org/project/publishcontent
2. https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished
3. https://www.drupal.org/project/override_node_options

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overwrite action button using hook_form_alter().

$form['actions']['delete']

Instead standard action use your own.